# What is a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't find a real definition of what a docker-compose file is.

Is it correct to say this:

> A docker-compose file is a YAML file that allows us to deploy multiples Docker containers at the same time.

I'd like to be able to explain a bit better what a docker-compose file is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A docker-compose.yml is a config file for [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

It allows to deploy, combine, and configure multiple docker containers at the same time. The Docker "rule" is to outsource every single process to its own Docker container.

Take for example a simple web application: You need a server, a database, and PHP. So you can set three docker containers with Apache2, PHP, and MySQL.

The advantage of Docker Compose is easy configuration. You don't have to write a big bunch of commands into Bash. You can predefine it in the docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: example_db
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: rootpw
php:
    image: php
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - ./SRC:/var/www/
    links:
        - db
```

As you can see in my example, I define port forwarding, volumes for external data, and links to the other Docker container. It's fast, reproducible, and not that hard to understand.

The Docker Compose file format is formally [specified](https://compose-spec.io/) which enables docker-compose.yml files being executed with something else than Docker, [Podman](https://github.com/containers/podman-compose) for example.

Answer (score 14):

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a tool that allows you to deploy and manage multiple containers at the same time.
A `docker-compose.yml` file contains instructions on how to do that.
In this file, you instruct **Docker Compose** for example to:

- From where to take the `Dockerfile` to build a particular image
- Which ports you want to expose
- How to link containers
- Which ports you want to bind to the host machine

**Docker Compose** reads that file and executes commands.
It is used *instead of all optional parameters* when building and running a single docker container.

Example:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      links:
          - django:django
          - angular:angular
      ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "8000:8000"
          - "443:443"
      networks:
       - my_net
  django:
      build: ./django
      expose:
          - "8000"
      networks:
       - my_net
  angular:
      build: ./angular2
      links:
          - django:django
      expose:
          - "80"
      networks:
        - my_net
networks:
  my_net:
    external:
      name: my_net
```

This example instructs **Docker Compose** to:

- Build `nginx` from path ./nginx
- Links `angular` and `django` containers (so their IP in the Docker network is resolved by name)
- Binds ports `80`, `443`, `8000` to the host machine
- Add it to network `my_net`
  (so all 3 containers are in the same network and therefore accessible from each other)

Then something similar is done for the `django` and `angular` containers.
If you would use just Docker commands, it would be something like:

```
docker build --name nginx .
docker run --link django:django angular:angular --expose 80 443 8000 --net my_net nginx
```

So while you probably don't want to type all these options and commands for each image/container, you can write a `docker-compose.yml` file in which you write all these instructions in a human-readable format.

Answer (score 1):

If your project requires different services in a running state, you have to pull all those services’  images individually from Docker and start all of them in their containers every time you want to run your project. To overcome this exhausting process, Multi Containers (Docker Compose) was created.
Docker Compose is a YAML file to configure your application's services, and create and start all of them from your configuration with command (docker compose up).

Docker Compose is included in [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) for windows and macOS, and for linux you can download its binary file from [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases).

An example of docker-compose.yml for a project having postgres DB:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
        db:
            image: postgres
            environment:
                POSTGRES_DB: DB_name
                POSTGRES_USER: DB_user
                POSTGRES_PASSWORD: DB_password
            volumes:
                - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```